# Three.js animation with Mixamo

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, roblox

My goal is to make a ROBLOX like customization system for my game, where a user can choose between hundreds of pieces of clothing and accessories for their avatar. Now, I would like to use Mixamo to animate my character, but Mixamo needs a fully boned rig to download the animations. Now that's a problem: I need Blender to bone the rig, but each rig will be different since the user is creating his *own* character, and if I had all the rigs pre-made, there would be literally millions of combinations of characters!

The alternative, I'm thinking, is to use Tween.js, but that's a really bad way since it'll take a *ton* of work and time just to get a single animation, and it still won't be as good as Mixamo.

At this point, I'm sure you have no idea what I'm talking about, so here's an image to describe my issue:

[image: Diagram]

I hope the diagram made my problem more clear. Below I've listed some of the possibilities that could potentially solve this problem, but then again, not sure.

- Maybe you can download an animation from Mixamo without a specified rig to it, so you can apply it to any character?
- Maybe I just animate the base rig and then apply the textures for all the body parts (so instead of downloading all the rig possibilities, I just download all of the clothing textures)?

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: After reading your question, I'm not quite sure what your question is. Are you looking for advice on how to implement an avatar customization system? Do it specifically with Mixamo?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. You see, If I create a different rig for every single combination, then there will be countless. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who was wondering the same thing:
You should first download the desired animation from Mixamo on the base model (without the customizations). Once you load the animation into three.js, you should be able to see a group, which includes the components from which the model was made. You can then manually apply as many textures as you want to the desired parts of the rig. So, your model will move normally (like the animation), while having your character exactly how you or the user wants it.